# Finding the max of sum of the values in the inner nested defaultdict

Tags: python, sum, max, counter, defaultdict

Given a `defaultdict(Counter)` as such:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

x = {('a', 'z'): Counter({'crazy': 1, 'lazy': 1}),
     ('b', 'r'): Counter({'brown': 1}),
     ('d', 'o'): Counter({'dog': 1}),
     ('e', 'r'): Counter({'over': 1}),
     ('f', 'o'): Counter({'fox': 1}),
     ('h', 'e'): Counter({'the': 2}),
     ('j', 'u'): Counter({'jumps': 1}),
     ('l', 'a'): Counter({'lazy': 1}),
     ('m', 'p'): Counter({'jumps': 1}),
     ('o', 'g'): Counter({'dog': 1}),
     ('o', 'v'): Counter({'over': 1}),
     ('o', 'w'): Counter({'brown': 1}),
     ('o', 'x'): Counter({'fox': 1}),
     ('p', 's'): Counter({'jumps': 1}),
     ('r', 'o'): Counter({'brown': 1}),
     ('t', 'h'): Counter({'the': 2}),
     ('u', 'm'): Counter({'jumps': 1}),
     ('v', 'e'): Counter({'over': 1}),
     ('w', 'n'): Counter({'brown': 1}),
     ('z', 'y'): Counter({'crazy': 1, 'lazy': 1})}
```

I can access the values in the tuple key as such:

```
>>> x[('a', 'z')]
Counter({'crazy': 1, 'lazy': 1})
```

If I want to find the tuple key with the highest sum of the values in the inner dictionary, i.e. the Counter, I can do this:

```
>>> max([(sum(x[ng].values()), ng) for ng in x])
(2, ('z', 'y'))
>>> max([(sum(x[ng].values()), ng) for ng in x])[1]
('z', 'y')
```

I think the steps are a little convoluted to get the max values. **Is there a more straightforward way to get the max of sum of the values in the inner nested defaultdict?**

Note as much as possible don't recreate another object from `x`. This sample is small but the actual size of the `x` object can contain 1,000,000 keys and the inner counters could be in 10,000,000 in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the value in the iteration to avoid looking up the value with `[]`, but it's not that much cleaner:

```
max((sum(c.values()), key) for key, c in x.items())
```

You can provide max with a function which looks nice if you only want to return the key of the max entry:

```
max(x, key=lambda k: sum(x[k].values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

### `[]` are unneeded

```
print ( max((sum(x[ng].values()), ng) for ng in x)[1] )
```

### Cleaning up with .items()

```
print ( max((sum(v.values()), k) for k,v in x.items())[1] )
```

### Max w/ lambda version

```
print ( max(x, key=lambda y: sum(x[y].values())) )
```

### The `map` method

```
print ( max(map(lambda ng: (sum(x[ng].values()), ng), x))[1] )
```